# API Gateway invoking an older version of my lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function invoked from my browser. I know that is working because the response is correct. In my lambda, I want to write into a dynamo table so I updated my function to include this logic.

When I test my function in the lambda console it works as expected. When the lambda is called from the browser (via API Gateway), it does not execute any of the new code that I added.

Here is my code:

```
#set-up table connection 
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('XXXX')

tString = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")

#print("Received event: " +
#   json.dumps(event, indent=2))

#recieve parameters
if 'userid' in event: 
    userid = event['userid']
else:
    userid = 'nothing'
if 'token' in event: 
    token = event['token']
else:
    token = 'nothing'
if 'appid' in event: 
    appid = event['appid']
else:
    appid = 'connection'

response = table.put_item(
        Item = {
            'ID': userid,
            'token': 'test2',
            'appid': 'test2',
            'authApp': 'test2',
            'authUser': 'test2' 
        })
return userid
```

Comment: When it's invoked from Browser, are you sure you lambda actually succeeded? Since it's from browser, the way you set up the lambda integration with API Gateway  matters and the event can be significantly different. Could you share your API Gateway set up?

Comment: Using Cloudwatch to check the running lambda details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you invoking your Lambda via API Gateway?  If so, check the Lambda integration for the endpoint you are hitting in API Gateway and see if the version/alias of the Lambda function is hardcoded.  You can find this by looking at the value of "Lambda Function" in the Integration Request section of the API Gateway method:

```
Lambda Function: my_function:dev
```

In the example above, this means your API Gateway is invoking the "dev" version of the "my_function" lambda.

Then check in the Lambda console if the version/alias you are invoking in the console, the one with the recent DynamoDB changes, matches the version/alias that is being invoked by the API Gateway.

I have spent a day or two smashing my head against the keyboard trying to figure out why my updates weren't being executed to realize that the API Gateway was pointing at a different/older version of my function.